# PHP Template (no template engine) Not Rendering After Refactor

Tags: php, templates

I had working code for creating a html template using pure php (no template engine). The code rendered the `<select>` to the page correctly. I asked for a code review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/120333/97680)

It caused my code not to compile. I saw an obvious error in that the `static $template = 'select_template.php';` was completely deleted causing `$template` to be undefined so I have fixed that.

Now the `CountrySelect` template simply does not render any html to the page at all and I'm unsure why, as there is no php error in the php error log. I cannot say if the `RegionSelect` template renders because I am not yet using it, but I assume it does not as it is the same except for the `$viewData`

**Question: How do I get my CountrySelect template to render again?**

**Bonus points: I would actually like both my `$template` and `$templatePath` to be constants either in the interface or the abstract class if possible. Can that be done?**

Here is my code:

```
country_select.php

<?php
interface iSelect {
    public static function display();
}

abstract class AreaSelect implements iSelect {

    static $template = 'select_template.php';

    public static function displayData($viewData) {
            if ( class_exists( 'View' ) ) {

                // Get the full path to the template file.

                $templatePath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . static::$template;

                // Return the rendered HTML
                return View::render( $templatePath, $viewData );

            }
            else {
                return "You are trying to render a template, but we can't find the View Class";
            }
    }
}

class CountrySelect extends AreaSelect {
    public static function display() {
        $viewData = array(
            "options" => '_countries',
            "optionsText" => 'name',
            "optionsValue" => 'geonameId',
            "value" => 'selectedCountry',
            "caption" => 'Country'
        );
        parent::displayData($viewData);
    }
}

class RegionSelect extends AreaSelect {
    public static function display() {
        $viewData = array(
            "options" => '_regions',
            "optionsText" => 'name',
            "optionsValue" => 'name',
            "value" => 'selectedCity',
            "caption" => 'Region'
        );
        parent::displayData($viewData);
    }
}
```

view.php:

```
<?php

/** View.php **/

class View {

    /**
     * -------------------------------------
     * Render a Template.
     * -------------------------------------
     * 
     * @param $filePath - include path to the template.
     * @param null $viewData - any data to be used within the template.
     * @return string - 
     * 
     */
    public static function render( $filePath, $viewData = null ) {

        // Was any data sent through?
        ( $viewData ) ? extract( $viewData ) : null;

        ob_start();
        include ( $filePath );
        $template = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $template;
    }
}
?>
```

select_template.php:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <div class="select">
        <span class="arr"></span>
        <select data-bind="options: <? echo $options ?>,
            optionsText: '<? echo $optionsText ?>',
            optionsValue: '<? echo $optionsValue ?>',
            value: <? echo $value ?>,
            optionsCaption: '<? echo $caption ?>'">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the literal HTML that did get output to the php page (when using [my version on code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/120333)) and now is completely missing from the html output of the index.php page:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <div class="select">
        <span class="arr"></span>
        <select data-bind="options: _countries,
            optionsText: 'name',
            optionsValue: 'geonameId',
            value: selectedCountry,
            optionsCaption: 'Country'">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Calling the template within index.php to actually render it (this has not changed as it was not included in my code review):

```
 <?php
                                require 'scripts/back_end/views/country_select.php';
                                require 'scripts/back_end/views/view.php';
                                //echo View::render('select_template.php');
                                echo CountrySelect::display();
                            ?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing `return` before `parent::displayData($viewData);` in both `CountrySelect` and `RegionSelect`.  Note that you also don't have any code that actually injects your `$viewData` values into the template. Not sure if you're expecting that to happen or not.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks, I will try the `return` tonight. In my version of the code that is in my code review question, it does render the html to the php page with the injected `$viewData`. I have now added an example to my question on here of the literal HTML that did get output to the php page (when using my version on code review) and now does not.

Comment: Sorry, it probably does interpret the variables in the template in your environment. I have short tags turned off, so I had to use the full `<?php` instead of just `<?` in select_template.php to get it to work.  So just adding the `return`s will probably do it for you.